# Can I trust manually sequencing an integer field in Postgres, if done inside a transaction?

Tags: database, postgresql, transactions

I have a table called `ticket`, and it has a field called `number` and a foreign key called `client` that needs to work much like an auto-field (incrementing by 1 for each new record), except that the client chain needs to be able specify the starting number. This isn't a unique field because multiple clients will undoubtedly use the same numbers (e.g. start at `1001`). In my application I'm fetching the row with the highest `number`, and using that `number` `+ 1` to make the next record's `number`. This all takes place inside of a single transaction (the fetching and the saving of the new record). Is it true that I won't have to worry about a `ticket` ever getting an incorrect (duplicate) `number` under a high load situation, or will the transaction protect from that possibility? (note: I'm using PostgreSQL 9.x)

Comment: What if the transaction is rolled back?

Comment: @mattb - well doesn't that mean that nothing will have changed in the database, and therefore the next `number` will be available again? I don't intend on retrying the operation withe same digit in multiple transactions.

Comment: Do you have a unique index on (client,number) and if not, why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without locking the *whole* table on every insert/update, no.  The way transactions work on PostgreSQL means that new rows that appear as a result of concurrent transactions never conflict with each other; and thats exactly what would be happening.

You need to make sure that updates actually *cause* the same rows to conflict.  You would basically need to implement something similar to the mechanic used by PostgreSQL's native sequences.

What I would do is add another column to the table referenced by your `client` column to represent the `last_val` of the sequence's you'll be using.  So each transaction would look sort of like this:

```
BEGIN;

SET TRANSACTION SERIALIZABLE;

UPDATE clients 
  SET footable_last_val = footable_last_val + 1 
  WHERE clients.id = :client_id;

INSERT INTO footable(somecol, client_id, number) 
  VALUES (:somevalue, 
          :client_id, 
          (SELECT footable_last_val 
             FROM clients 
             WHERE clients.id = :client_id));

COMMIT;
```

So that the first update into the clients table *fails* due to a version conflict before reaching the insert.

Comment: Version conflict? Are you assuming the transaction is running in serializable mode? (As opposed to the default "read committed").

Comment: @Daniel: hmm, yes, i was assuming that.  I'm a tad spoiled by the framework I use; which sets this by default.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy - do you use Django? This is the framework I use.

Answer (score 1):

You do have to worry about duplicate numbers.

The typical problematic scenario is: transaction T1 reads N, and creates a new row with N+1. But **before T1 commits**, another transaction T2 sees N as the max for this client and creates another new row with N+1 => conflict.

There are many ways to avoid this; here is a simple piece of plpgsql code that implements one method, assuming a unique index on (client,number). The solution is to let the inserts run concurrently but in the event of a unique index violation, retry with refreshed values until it's accepted (it's not a busy loop, though, since concurrent inserts are blocked until other transactions commit)

```
do
$$
begin
 loop
  BEGIN
    -- client number is assumed to be 1234 for the sake of simplicity
    insert into the_table(client,number)
       select 1234, 1+coalesce(max(number),0) from the_table where client=1234;
    exit; 
  EXCEPTION
   when unique_violation then -- nothing (keep looping)
  END;
 end loop;
end$$;
```

This example is a bit similar to the [UPSERT implementation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-UPSERT-EXAMPLE) from the PG documentation.
It's easily transferable into a plpgsql function taking the client id as input.